# Roblox Argument 1 Missing Or Nil

Tags: roblox

I am trying to make a block that when it is hit by a specific tool, it dissapers and gives the player some XP. However, when I run my code I get an error saying "Argument 1 Missing Or Nil". My code is below.

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent.Name == 'Vacuum' then
        local plr = hit.Parent.Parent.Name
        script.Parent.CanCollide = false
        script.Parent.Transparency = 1
        local exp = 2
        local player = game.Players:FindFirstChild(plr.Name)
        local plrcurrentexp = player.leaderstats.JobXP.Value
            plrcurrentexp.Value = plrcurrentexp + exp
        wait(120)
        script.Parent.CanCollide = true
        script.Parent.Transparency = 0  
    end
end)
```

Please Help!

Comment: Does it give you a line number. There are a bunch of arguments (things in brackets) there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 problems, of which both are the same type of problem.

**Problem 1**

The first problem is finding the player. You set `plr = hit.parent.Parent.name`, but then run `FindFirstChild(plr.Name)`, but that doesn't work since `plr` is already the player's `Name`. Instead you should do:

```
local player = game.Players:FindFirstChild(plr)
```

**Problem 2**

The second problem is in your assignment statement:

```
local exp = 2
local player = game.Players:FindFirstChild(plr.Name)
local plrcurrentexp = player.leaderstats.JobXP.Value
plrcurrentexp.Value = plrcurrentexp + exp
```

On that last line you're trying to set the `Value` of `JobXP`, however `plrcurrentexp` isn't `JobXP`, it's the `Value`.

So what you're doing right now is `player.leaderstats.JobXP.Value.Value = plrcurrentexp + exp`, which is wrong.

Instead do this:

```
local exp = 2
local player = game.Players:FindFirstChild(plr.Name)
local plrcurrentexp = player.leaderstats.JobXP
plrcurrentexp.Value = plrcurrentexp.Value + exp
```